Gack id -2018116553 for embedded service messaging deployment on a scratch org
The following error happens when we try to create embedded service messaging deployment on a scratch org

An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 1163693033-53404 (-2018116553)

Why does it happen? Is this not supposed to work on a scratch org?

Are you creating scratch org using org shape? If yes can you try creating scratch org without org shape. (https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwrWAAS/cant-create-a-digital-experience-cloud-site-using-org-shape)

yes, I am using org shape

There is known issue about creating scratch org using org shape
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwrWAAS/cant-create-a-digital-experience-cloud-site-using-org-shape
